# Is "Virus Scanner Plus" a legitimate product?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

I have ["Virus Scanner Plus"](https://xp.apple.com/report/2/its_mail_sf?responseType=redirect&emailType=share_desktopApp&lang=en_us&eventType=linkClick&redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fvirus-scanner-plus%2Fid595374522%3Fmt%3D12) (ostensibly) by [Bitdefender](https://www.bitdefender.com) installed on my Mac from the App Store (and have had for a few years). But, although the app was recently updated in the App Store, it is [not listed as a Bitdefender product](https://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/all.html), and Bitdefender's support says

> We do not have Virus Scaner Plus for MAC

Is "Virus Scanner Plus" a legitimate product? Is it in fact made by Bitdefender? If so is there an upgrade path?

Comment: This seems like something you should email Bitdefender about

Comment: @BlackMagic: I did: that's how I got "We do not have Virus Scaner Plus for MAC" (after 6 days and about 20 e-mails). But if that's the case, someone is spoofing them in the App Store, so I'm looking for corroboration.

Comment: it is referenced by Bitdefender on their own website here https://www.bitdefender.com/support/removing-bitdefender-virus-scanner-plus-1247.html so it seems it is a legit product - maybe it's discontinued

Comment: @iain: Updated in the App Store a month ago.